# Need help creating For loop in Script editor to make Script run code on all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I have a script that I am trying to run on all sheets within a google doc and dont know how to make that work. IT works for one sheet, but I have numerous sheets all with the same format that need to be checked. Thanks.

Here's the script I am trying to apply to all sheets.

```
function sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message);
}


function timestamp() {
return new Date()
}

var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";


function test_sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.setActiveCell('A2');
  var criterion_cutoff = 5;
  var i = 0;
  var startRow = 2;
  var addr;
  var subj;
  var msg;
  var timecheck
  do {
    addr = cell.offset(i,0).getValue();
    subj = cell.offset(i,1).getValue();
    msg = cell.offset(i,2).getValue();
    criterion = cell.offset(i,3).getValue();
    timecheck = cell.offset(i,11).getValue();
    if (timecheck > 0) {
      if(criterion < criterion_cutoff) {
        sendEmail(addr,subj,msg);
        Browser.msgBox('Sending email to: ' + addr);
      }}
    i++;
  } while( cell.offset(i, 0).getValue().length > 0 )
  sheet.getRange(2, 5).setValue(timestamp());  
  Browser.msgBox('Done!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of IDs that you want to apply the script to by making the following changes:
1. Change

```
function test_sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

to:

```
function test_sendEmail(sheetID) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
```

2 . Define an array of IDs of sheets that you want to change:

```
var idArray = [Spreadsheet1_id, Spreadsheet2_id, ...];
```

3 . create a loop that would cycle through all the elements of the array

```
for(var k in idArray) test_sendEmail(idArray[i]);
```

If you don't want to manually populate the idArray, you can create a function that would pull IDs of all spreadsheets in your Google Drive. If that is what you want, then use the following code instead of the line of code I provided you with in point 2.

```
var sprArr =  DocsList.getFilesByType("spreadsheet");
var idArray;
for(var k in sprArr) idArray.push(sprArr[i].getId());
```

Comment: Would you mind inserting notes? I'm having trouble making it work

Comment: What do you mean by "inserting notes"?

Comment: Just explain exactly what each change does.

So the first change in step 1 means I need to insert the unique Sheet Id for my sheet into the step. It will assign the variable sheet to be equal to the specific sheet which is identified by the id.

Im assuming that's correct. Sorry to ask for the hand holding, but I like to understand what's happening. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out. Thanks for all the help. Works just fine.